# calculate feedback factor in feedback circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, feedback, gain, loop-gain

Below is an exercise with solution about feedback network. I am wondering how the feedback factor is calculated like that. Could anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't accept their answers based on the fact that they appear to believe that there is an impedance from the input (base) to ground of 4k + 1k - what happened to Q4's rE affecting this?

Comment: Are you talking about breaking the loop to calculate open loop gain?

Comment: Yes, their way of doing it.

Comment: For calculate open loop gain (forward gain) should we insert input voltage right at the base after 500 ohms resistor because that point is the true input of forward amplifier?

Comment: I just look at it and see that the closed loop gain will be about 8.

Comment: how did you calculate it?

Comment: 4000/500 = 8, just like an op-amp with negative feedback. This makes input Z = 500 and of course output Z is rE of the final transistor which is going to be somewhere between 10 ohm and 30 ohm. In other words, I'm past the point where I care to do precise computations on circuits like this LOL.

Comment: And I've just noticed in your question that Ic = 1mA hence rE will be 26 ohms (26mV/Ic). Va is infinity (in your question) hence the gain will be 8. I can make this an answer if you want.

Comment: Regarding the feedback factor: f=Vbase/Vout for Vin=0.

Comment: Regarding the feedback factor: f=Vb1/Vout for Vin=0. Assuming rbe1=h11=hie1=5k (Ic=1mA) we can calculate Ve4=ic*0.8k and Ve4/Vout=0.8k/4k. From this, f=Vb1/Vout=(4.45/8.45)0.8k/4k. So we arrive at a feedback factor of app. f=0.1.

Comment: More than that - I doubt if the shown method for open-loop gain calculation is correct.

Comment: @LvW: I think so too. I think that the open loop gain should be from the base to Vout not from Vin to Vout. Is that same as yours?

Comment: No - I think the calculation based on Vin is OK - however, in the right part of the 2nd figure I miss the influence of the finite base-emitter resistance (rbe=hie) for Q1.More than that, for the input resistace (second picture) where is the influence of the low impedance node of the emitter (Q4) ?

Comment: @LvW: I think these are just approximation. They assumed that bjt input resistance is zero.
However, I am confused about loop gain, it is the gain of feedforward and feedback network. But from Vin to Vout is not feedforward. Should it be from Vbase to Vout?

Comment: Input resistance of ZERO??? Feedback factor is defined as percentage of output fed back to the input.

Comment: I don't see anyone with the correct answer with gain at the collector.  = -80

Comment: What book is this?

Answer (score 1):

Gain at Q4 collector is 40.

This can be seen as the the output 4k load is driven by a current source (Q4 collector). Current is found as input current Vin/.5k which flows through the 4k feedback R. Feedback drives emitter of Q4 to -Vin/.5k * 4k=-8*Vin causing the net emitter current to be (Vin)*(1/0.5k+(4k/0.5k)*(1/1k))=vin*10e-3. Multiply by 4k and divide by Vin to get 40.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the gain stages is 4K/(0.026 / 1mA) = 4K/26 = 150X or 42dB. Total low frequency gain is 126dB (2 Million), ignoring any loading by the next stage's DC rin (probably significant, but no beta is given, so ignore that gain-shunting).

Gain will be Rf/Rin = 8x (14dB). There is a rather effective Virtual Gnd activity, thus Rin sets the input resistance.

DC Rout will be 26 ohms/gain_margin = 26 / (2million/8) = 26/ 250,000 or 0.1 milliohm.

Comment: I think, loading of the following stages must not be neglected because the expected rin (rbe=hie) will be in the same order as a the collector resistors.

Comment: correct---but we have no beta data; if same (4K || 4K), the open loop gain remains at 8X, Rin still 500, and Rout increases from 100uOhm to 800uOhm.

Comment: .... "if the output were on Q4 emitter" is missing at the beginning of your answer